# Как из одного списка создать второй, в котором будут чётные числа?

Tags: python

```
def get_odd_numbers(numbers):
    odd_numbers = []
    for number in numbers:
        if number % 2 == 1:
            odd_numbers.append(number)
    return odd_numbers
print(get_odd_numbers(numbers))
(numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 3, 45, 11, 8, 35])
(Получилось сделать с нечётными, но не знаю, как с чётными)
```

Comment: 1. У вас неправильно создан цикл. 2. Используйте оператор `%` для получения остатка от числа и в зависимости от него (остатка) и получайте ваши нечётные числа.

Comment: Ну смотрите, у вас `list_nums` это итератор (Обычно его называют `i` или `e`), то есть он всегда меняется на каждой итерации, то есть у вас итератор это массив который вы уже создали (Что не есть правильно). Плюс к тому массив который итерируется (`range(1, n + 1)`) имеет переменную `n`, о которой нигде ни сказано, так что непонятно что и где у вас итерируется. Советую вам повторно пройти тему циклов, т.к. судя по коду вы её не до конца поняли, есть множество видео уроков по циклам на YouTube, статей в интернете и в конце концов в книгах отдельные главы посвящены им.

Answer (score 0):

Мне в задании нужно было найти чётные и нечётные, а также записать их в порядке убывания. Доработал код и получилось вот это.

```
def get_odd_numbers(numbers):
    odd_numbers = []
    for number in numbers:
        if number % 2 == 1:
            odd_numbers.append(number)
    return odd_numbers
def get_a_numbers(numbers):
    a_numbers = []
    for number in numbers:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            a_numbers.append(number)
    return a_numbers
print(sorted(get_odd_numbers(numbers),reverse=True))
print(sorted(get_a_numbers(numbers),reverse=True))
```

Comment: `get_a_numbers` неправильно на английском так-то (Пишется вот так: `get_numbers`, без `a`), вы наверно хотели написать `get_even_numbers`. Также непонятно к чему тут сортировка, вопрос ведь был про отфильтровывание массива. В любом случае ответ правильный, вы молодец, что сами разобрались :)

Comment: Я добавил -а-, чтобы не было ошибок) Я просто изменил list_nums на просто numbers. А так я выполнял задание, в котором требовалось отсортировать именно через sorted) 
Иногда мне просто лень писать точные названия :3